Woocommerce Cannot change anything in the checkout using manager plugins
I'm a beginner in WooCommerce, but I find that there are problems that are not connected with my experience.
Briefly, I have a fresh xampp installation on Ubuntu, a new database for my experiments, and the latest copy of WordPress. I started with the Deli theme, which is one of three free Woo recommendations. I have installed WooCommerce and Checkout Manager. And there is a problem: any change in the checkout page using the manager didn't actually change anything. I have studied and searched and actually found that there are issues with the Woo 8.6 branch, but nothing concrete for the solution. 

Because you need to switch cart and checkout Blocks version pages to Classic cart and checkout (legacy shortcode).
